# Xamarin Android App crashes when attempting to debug on a physical device

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2022

I am attempting to debug an android app created using Xamarin Forms in Visual Studio 2022.  However, the app crashes on launch and no output is shown.  When running the app normally, there are no issues.  Running or debugging the app on the emulator poses no problems, either.  Unfortunately, I have no other information to provide that I can think of.

Comment: You can view logs and retrieve crash dumps using adb

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=adb+crash+logs

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: My investigation let me to believe its a port issue with debugger:
adbd failed to connect to socket 'tcp:8848':

This is the error i got, have a look if your logs show the same

Answer (score 1):

Just hit this problem, the work around that worked for me was disable "Use Fast Deployment" in the Properties->Android Options.

The build was crashing before any debugger or log output was generated.

Comment: Visual Studio display this message: "There were deployment errors. Continue?" and with Yes or No answer, Visual Studio abort the Debug run instance

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug with Visual Studio 2022. I came across similar issue, I've fixed it by changing in your csproj file:

```
 <EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>true</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>
```

To

```
 <EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>false</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>
```

It worked like a charm for me :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not help.  Thanks for the suggestion!